# Updating Clob?

Tags: oracle10g, clob

I have a table abc(serial int primary key,details clob).I want to update the details field of the table.The data I want to update is more than 4000 characters.So anyone please tell me in details how to update the clob column using pl/sql or any other method??

Comment: You mean `insert` data into a clob field?

Comment: `PLSQL` does not support the `insertion of strings` greater than `32k` at one time.To work around that limitation and if your text is greater than 32000 characters, you will need to send the text in chunks of data with each chunk should not exceed the 32k limit (a loop thing) and store each chunk in the same CLOB field.

Comment: No my data will be less than 32k but more than 4k.However,please provide me with a code or something to do this.

Comment: @ BEn-Not insert.I already have inserted data in the clob field.Now I want to update that data.

Comment: Finally found the solution.Here's the code that helped me....
StringReader clob = new StringReader("");
pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("update activity set REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pStmt.setCharacterStream(1, clob, 0);
pStmt.setLong(2, 1);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
Here in pstmt.setCharacterStream() the last parameter is the length of the clob data with which I want to update.Thanks everybody for giving a look at my code.